# How to add CORS Headers in Woocommerce API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cors

I'm trying to fix an issue with an Ajax request and the woocommerce API. Actually, when i request WC, the CORS Headers are missing. This is the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mywebsite.com/woocommerce/?wc-api=software-api&request=check&email=email&license_key=license&product_id=product' from origin 'https://www.client.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I already add this code to my theme functions.php file :

```
function add_cors_http_header(){
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, READ');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token,authorization,XMLHttpRequest, user-agent, accept, x-requested-with');
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");

  if ( 'OPTIONS' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    status_header(200);
    exit();
  }
}

add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');
```

The error still here. I don't understand where i should put the code to add CORS Headers to my reponse.

**EDIT**

This is the request which fail (from Chrome Dev Tools):

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Tried to add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in my .htaccess too, still not working.

**EDIT 3**

I tried to add Header directives directly from plesk panel. It's seems to affect the error (YAY !!!). When i add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` the error is now:

[image]

Comment: Did you check if the headers are set by your web- or proxy-server? I guess you can't easily override them in that case...

Comment: No, i didn't do you have any documentation i could read about that ? I'm really disappointed about this part

Comment: I found https://enable-cors.org/server.html as a good starting point - if the webserver is under your control. Otherwise you may have to talk to your hosting company.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response? Is it a response to the CORS preflight OPTIONS request?

Comment: @user127091 thank's for the link, i will check this deeper and try to contact OVH ( Hoster)

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank's for your help, there is no status code in the network pane on my request. [Check this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/fppjJ5N.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to @user127091 comment, i solved this issue by adding headers directly to the server configuration (Plesk in my case).

Comment: please describe more how add which line into which file?